# Two y-axes plot for multiple data set in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to create two y-axes plot in Matlab.
I have two groups of data, with each group having three plots of similar type. When I am trying to plot it, the scaling on right hand side y-axis get messed up. I would appreciate some help.

```
X = [50, 100, 200, 400];

YSKL_Temporal_WOFAE    = [3.2000       2.3354      1.9428          1.7658];
YSKL_Spatial_WOFAE     = [0.9225       0.9724      1.0986          1.1770];
YSKL_Spatial_WithFAE   = [0.2635       0.1653      0.1513           0.1618];

YMSRE_Temporal_WOFAE    = [0.3559       0.3027    0.2733          0.2636];
YMSRE_Spatial_WOFAE     = [.3151       .2689      .2551           0.2524];
YMSRE_Spatial_WithFAE   = [.0933       .0648      0.0663          0.0640];

figure(1);
[AX, p1, p2] = plotyy(X, YSKL_Temporal_WOFAE, X, YMSRE_Temporal_WOFAE);
set(AX,'XTick', X);   % This fixes X-axis tick mark (same as data axis)

set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','SKL Score') 
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','Norm. Residuals') 
xlabel('Time (\musec)') 
title('SKL and Norm. Residual plotted on different y-axes') 
set(p1,'LineStyle','--')
set(p2,'LineStyle',':')

axes(AX(1))
hold on
plot(X, YSKL_Spatial_WOFAE);
hold on
plot(X, YSKL_Spatial_WithFAE);
ylim([0 4])
hold off

axes(AX(2))
hold on
plot(X, YMSRE_Spatial_WOFAE);
hold on
plot(X, YMSRE_Spatial_WithFAE);
ylim([0.0 0.4])
hold off
```

Plot looks like this:
[image]

Please notice the scale on right y-axes

Regards,
Dushyant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second (right hand side) y-axis tick labels are "frozen" after the call to [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html). When adjusting the `ylim` on `AX(2)` this has no effect on the labels.
Therefore, the [axes appearance](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) has to be reset to `auto`.
Using the following code with the example from the question:

```
axes(AX(2))
hold on
plot(X, YMSRE_Spatial_WOFAE);
hold on
plot(X, YMSRE_Spatial_WithFAE);
ylim([0.0 0.4])
% include the following statement to allow 
% the second y-axis to reset the ticks:
set(AX(2), 'YTickMode', 'auto', 'YTickLabelMode', 'auto')
hold off
```

Will yield this plot:

[image]